Proof of second partials test for saddle points - why does Hessian need to be nonsingular?
Suppose $f:U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is $C^2$ on $U$ and $\nabla f(x)=0$ at $x \in U$. If $Hf(x)$ is indefinite and nonsingular—that is, if it has both positive and negative eigenvalues and none of its eigenvalues are $0$, then $f$ has a saddle point at $x$ by the Second Partial Derivative Test.
I am trying to prove this result, but I do not understand where the part about $Hf(x)$ being nonsingular comes in. My attempt is as follows. With a change of coordinates, we can write $h^THf(x)h$ as $y^TDy$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with all the eigenvalues of $Hf(x)$ as its entries, and $y$ being the coordinates of $h$ with respect to the eigenbasis. Let $\{v_1,...v_n\}$ be the eigenbasis, all of unit length. Then $$h^THf(x)h=y^TDy=\lambda_1y_1^2+\cdots+\lambda_ny_n^2.$$
Suppose $\lambda_1>0$. Then $h^THf(x)h>0$ for any $y_1$ as long as $y_2,...y_n=0$. Taking $h=y_1v_1$, we have
$$f(x+h)-f(x)=\frac{1}{2} hHf(x)h+E(h)=\frac{1}{2}\lambda_1y_1^2+E(h)$$
where $E(h)$ is the error of the quadratic approximation. If $E(h)\ge 0$, then $f(x+h)-f(x)>0$. Therefore assume $E(h)<0$. Fix $\epsilon<\lambda_1/2$. Then for all small enough $h$, i.e., all small enough $y_1$, $|E(h)|<\epsilon \lVert h \rVert^2=\epsilon y_1^2$. We thus have
$$f(x+h)-f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\lambda_1y_1^2-|E(h)|\ge\frac{1}{2}\lambda_1y_1^2-\epsilon y_1^2>0.$$
Assuming that $\lambda_2<0$ and employing a similar argument, we thus see that along $v_1$, $f$ is growing, but along $v_2$, $f$ is decreasing. This tells us $f$ has a saddle point at $x$.
Is my reasoning correct? Where does nonsingularity come in? As long as there is one positive eigenvalue and one negative eigenvalue the argument holds; why do we need to ensure that all eigenvalues are nonzero?

The non-singularity comes in as soon as you state $\lambda_1 > 0$ or $\lambda_2 <0$. Else, every eigenvalue might be zero.

@HyperbolicPDEfriend: “Indefinite” means that there's at least one positive eigenvalue and at least one negative eigenvalue, right?

@lightweaver: Wikipedia agrees with you – see item 3 here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test#Functions_of_many_variables.

@HansLundmark Interesting! But the article does state the invertibility of the Hessian as a condition for the test. If it does not apply to the third item, then it must apply to either the first or second... but in those cases the fact that the Hessian is invertible is automatically satisfied, right?

Yes, that's a confusing formulation. Invertibility is automatic in cases 1 and 2 (as you say), and irrelevant in case 3 (as the Wikipedia article itself says!).

@HansLundmark Ah, thank goodness. I thought I was going crazy. Thank you very much for your help!
